# How to define a function to modify data submitted to the server on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I know that DataTables have the `ajax.url()` method for updating the data source URL, but I would like to know if there is a way I can change the function that is used to prepare the data to be POSTed on Ajax request. In the example below I would like to replace it with `dataFunc`.

The initialization part works fine.

```
function updateDataTable(dataFunc) {
    // If DataTable initialised then update to correct function
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#companyTable")) {
        var companyTable = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#companyTable");
        companyTable.settings().ajax.data = dataFunc;
        companyTable.ajax.reload();
    } else {
        $("#companyTable").DataTable({
            bFilter: false,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/GetCompanyRows",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataFunc
            },
....
```

Comment: Use `done:` of jQuery Ajax.

Comment: I want to change the data function which is what prepares the data to be POSTed.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` can take a function where you can do all sorts of things, not the least of which is using localstorage. Check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data#function) option to define a function that can be used to manipulate the data before it's sent to the server.

```js
$('#companyTable').DataTable({
   searching: false,
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax: {
      url: "/api/GetCompanyRows",
      type: "POST",
      data: function ( d ){
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an alternative to Pro Hands solution, which allowed me to update the settings directly.

```
companyTable.settings()[0].ajax.data = dataFunc;
companyTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: See [`settings()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/settings%28%29) page: *The information in this object is generally considered to be private and should not be used directly.*

Comment: Use `ajax.data` as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33359410/3549014) as a proper way to define a function.